# Regular expression to capture string between square brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have an array that its first element ***might*** contains something like `[some text, here. That's some text]`
I'm trying to figure out a pattern to check if such string exists and if not create it but having problem with making the pattern. Here's what I've done so far

```
$pattern = '/^\[*\]$/';
if(preg_match($pattern,$exploded[0])){
    $name = array_shift($exploded);
}else{
    $name = "[Unnamed import] - " .gmdate("His");
}
```

But I always get [Unnamed import] - 032758 even when I'm sure that pattern match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex `^\[*\]$` is incorrect.

```
^   - Start anchor
\[  - A literal [
*   - Quantifier for zero or more
\]  - A literal ]
$   - End anchor
```

The quantifier `*` applies to the part before it, in this case it applies to `[`. I guess you've confused the `*` with its usage in ***shell where it means any characters any number of times.***

So your regex matches zero or more of `[` at the beginning of the string and one `]` at the end of the string.

The equivalent of shell's `*` in regex is `.*` which matchs any character (except newline) any number of times. So you can try the regex `^\[.*\]$`

Alternatively you can try: `^\[[^\]]*\]$`

Answer (score 1):

The `*` by itself doesn't represent multiple characters. You need dot (=any char) followed by the asterisk `.*`, else the asterisk means to match zero or more `[` chars - because it always quantifies the preceeding character.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking to see if a string begins with `[` and ends with a `]`. You can easily do it without regex too as:

```
if(strlen($str) && $str[0] == '[' && $str[strlen($str)-1] == ']') {
        // pattern found.
}
```